# Error when calling the URL for saving JSON in database: String is too long

Tags: ajax, json, api

This is the method from the controller api :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveFloor(int floorID, string json)
    {
        Floor floor = db.FloorSet.Find(floorID);
        floor.SavedJson = json;
        floorRepository.Update(floor);
        floorRepository.Save();
    }
```

Then I made an ajax call to pass the URL.

```
   function SavingFloor(FloorId, Json) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Floor/SaveFloor?FloorID=" + FloorId + "&json=" + Json,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm trying to save JSON in database (datatype: nvarchar(MAX)), when I call the URL that executes the saving, I get this error `Error HTTP 404.15 - Not Found` and it says that the filter module applications is configured to deny a request if the string is too long.

So, what should I do? the JSON that I generate **is** in fact supposed to be too long, and that's the purpose. Please help.

Comment: Send the JSON string as the POST body not as part of the URL!

Comment: And SQL Server is tagged because...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the JSON string as the POST body not as part of the URL. Send it as text and `json_decode` on the server.

```
function SavingFloor(FloorId, Json) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Floor/SaveFloor?FloorID=" + FloorId,
        type: "POST",
        data: Json,
        dataType: 'text/html',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: json_decode on the server, could you please explain? :/

Comment: This way you receive the JSON as plain text (coming in the POST body). So whatever server side language you use, you have to decode the text (it would be `json_decode($jsonString);` with PHP) to get the original objects back.

Comment: So I have to decode the text in the controller method?

Comment: Sorry, I find this hard because this is the first time that I deal with JSON.